# Cocos2D: Run a parent update method with custom interval

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I´m trying to put a together a small level system for my game. I want a update method that takes care of my game main logic. So I declared a method in my parent class .h file:

Level.h:

```
-(void)gameLogicTick:(ccTime)dt;
```

Then I do the implementation in Level.m, don´t think the exact code is relevant.

I created a subclass of Level called Forest. In the Forest init-method I would like to specify the interval of *gameLogicTick*, I did this:

```
[self schedule:@selector(gameLogicTick:)interval:5.0f];
```

This makes my game crash(after 5 seconds) with no debug message what so ever.

So how can I create a schedule update-method where I can specify the interval in the current class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is ok. Perhaps the Forest object got deallocated (ie because it was never added as child to a parent node for example) and the next time CCScheduler updates the scheduled methods, it will try to run your method on an already released instance.

You should enable the global exception breakpoint in Xcode to get more crash info and the exact line where the crash occurs.

Comment: Yeah, I use it for my update-method without a interval.   `[self schedule:@selector(tick:)];` which works just fine.

Comment: UPDATE: Seems like the problem was the method I was calling inside the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try messing with the parent class `gameLogicTick:` method.  Leave that one to do its thing at full speed.  In your Forest.m, simply call

```
[self schedule:@selector(update:) interval: 5.0f];
```

then make sure you have the appropriate `update:(ccTime)` delta in your Forest implementation.  Just don't name it the same as your parent class's method and you won't have any problems.

Comment: Well, then I have to use that method in every subclass of Level, maybe I have to find another way then.